# using Vector3.up make th player do a more than 1 jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm new to c# and i just made a code that allow the player to jump and it worked fine but the problem is if i clicked the space button twice it will do a douple jump and if i keep doing it will fly.... I just want a 1 jump and if the player hit the ground can jump again no double jump ...
What i have tried is to change the  number that Multiply with vector3.up to just jump and made a

```
public float jump = 5f;
```

also didnt work any way here is my source code hope you understand the problem and help me

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float speed1;
    public float jump = 5f;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed1);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.Translate(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * jump, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait for Key Up before allowing another Key Down.

Comment: what do you mean please explain

Comment: @jdweng Just waiting for a KeyUp won't solve anything. The player can still press the jump button multiple times. I think the way to go here is to check if the player landed after jumping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a flag `wasGrounded` which you will set false after jumping. The player can only jump, when `wasGrounded == true`.
You also add a collider to your ground. Once the player touched the ground, you reset the `wasGrounded` flag to true.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float speed1;
    public float jump = 5f;

    private bool wasGrounded = true;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed1);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.Translate(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && wasGrounded)
        {
            wasGrounded = false;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.up * jump, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        // Change to string you compare it to to the tag of your ground gameobject.
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            wasGrounded = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Make sure to have "IsTrigger" set false on the ground`s collider.

Comment: if i set the ground to IsTrigger the player will fall from the ground and another thing! if i want to allow IsTrigger it cannot be pressed until i set convext true. please just answer this and i will accept your Q. as the right answer

Comment: OK I FIXED IT. by making another plane that has set the istrigger to false below the plane that has IsTrigger true. with -0.1 Y axis

Comment: You don't need to have another plane. Set IsTrigger to false and use the `OnCollisionEnter` method instad of `OnTriggerEnter`. I changed my answer, you can see the adjusted code there.